# Where to ask question about Windows Store app requirements?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where would be the correct site to ask a question about certification requirements for Windows Store apps? I asked the following question on Software Engineering and it was closed as off-topic:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180773/can-apps-using-skydrive-dropbox-for-roaming-data-be-certified-for-windows-stor

That's fine, but no suggestion was given on the correct destination. I deliberately chose not to post it on Stack Overflow, the site on which I am most active, because it seemed out-of-scope there. Is there a third programmer-related site for such questions?

Comment: Note: there is not a single forum hosted on Stack Exchange, only Q&A sites. I believe the correct place to ask that would be on a Microsoft Store forum or support board (i.e. ask Microsoft). Or sign up on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores

Answer (score 4):

Not every question is on topic somewhere on the SE network. This is by design. StackOverflow, as you noted, is specifically about code questions -  not the specific rules of various software stores. Similarly, Programmers.SE pretty clearly states that it's for **conceptual questions about software development** which is a definition that doesn't seem to fit your question either.

If you feel that there's enough of a base of experts and questions needing answered about a subject that isn't covered by an existing site, you can propose a new one at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), or search the existing proposals there to support one that fits your question.

Comment: There is an [App Store](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) proposal currently in the Commitment phase.